# Django how to show errors like in debug mode when DEBUG=False

Tags: django

When `DEBUG = False` I know errors do get mailed to ADMINs, but I would like to see the errors on the screen if I am logged in as `superuser`.

Is there a way to trigger it to show the debug screen instead of the 500.html for public users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned Sentry, or another service actually is a better choice. But for the case that you really want it your way, you would need a custom 500 handler and in there use `django.views.debug.technical_500_response`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/views/debug/

There's no real documentation on this - except for a simple comment -, since it's a method that shouldn't really be used externally. But you're free to use it:

urls.py

```
urls.handler500 = views.handler500
```

views.py

```
def handler500(request):
  if request.user.is_superuser():
      return technical_500_response(some, params, dontaskme)
  else:
      return render(request, "500.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not happy with the information generated in the emails, you're better off using something like [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) to track what happens on your site so that you can see what users come up against.

It uses standard python logging so you can set what level sentry is triggered by, and have various messages in your app to tell you pieces of information, and it automatically picks up the warnings/errors that might occur. It gives you all the kind of information you get from the standard debug error page with the stacktrace, context information etc.

Comment: Yes we are using graylog already, sorry that I didn't mention in my question.